# use variable defined for one sass mixin in another sass mixin

Tags: sass

I'm trying to use a var defined for one mixin in another mixin.

In my case, I definee the `$gutter` variable in the `container()` mixin.
I don't want to define it again for the `col()` mixin, so I was trying to get it into the `col()` mixin.

Here is what I've done so far:

```
@mixin container($gutter, $placeholder:"cols") {
  margin: 0 -#{$gutter / 2};
  %#{$placeholder} {
      margin-left: #{$gutter / 2};
      margin-right: #{$gutter / 2};
  }
}

@mixin cols($cols, $placeholder:"cols") {
  @extend %#{$placeholder};
  width: #{(100% / $cols) - $gutter};
}

.wrap {
  @include container(2%);

  > .half {
    @include cols(2);
  }

  > .third {
    @include cols(3);
  }

  > .fourth {
    @include cols(4);
  }

}
```

The css result I need is the following:

```
.wrap {
  margin: 0 -1%;
}
.wrap > .half, .wrap > .third, .wrap > .fourth {
  margin-left: 1%;
  margin-right: 1%;
}
.wrap > .half {
  width: 48%;
}
.wrap > .third {
  width: 31.33333%;
}
.wrap > .fourth {
  width: 23%;
}
```

Is there a way to do this? It fails in line 11 because `$gutter` is undefined. A global variable isn't the solution i need, because I have to use this mixin in different breakpoints with different gutters. So for each breakpoint will define `container()` and `cols()` for the elements again.

Answer (score 0):

You are creating a variable inside a mixin. Variables inside mixins are local they are not global. If you want to create a global variable from a mixin then you have to use the !global flag

you can rewrite the container mixin like this

```
@mixin container($gutter, $placeholder:"cols") {
  $gutter: $gutter !global;
  margin: 0 -#{$gutter / 2};
  %#{$placeholder} {
    margin-left: #{$gutter / 2};
    margin-right: #{$gutter / 2};
  }
}
```

Comment: That's great, thank you. I've tried to use it, but now I get the following error: `You may not @extend an outer selector from within @media.
You may only @extend selectors within the same directive.
From "@extend %cols" on line 11.` Do you have an idea how to fix this?